# onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:7

Tags: autodesk-forge

Today, I am getting an issue "onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:7" related to any model load on Forge viewer. 
It throws below error :

Error : "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Can anyone help me on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the email you sent to `forge.help@autodesk.com` and the query string of the request URL you provided, it seems that your Forge app didn't be hosted on a web server. The query string can be decoded from `domain=file%3A%2F%2F` to `domain=file://`.

Forge Viewer's main functions are built on the top of JavaScript's `XMLHttpRequest`, it cannot be used under `file://` protocol. So, please make sure your Forge app is hosted on a web server and you access it from valid URL from your web server.